# how to get objects degrees?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
float mcount=0;
mcount += 0.3;
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(mcount);
Clock.transform = transform;
```

i want GET Degree!
how to get rotation(degree) of this Object ? for exampke 90 degree.

i have Action Script 3 example :

```
myInt = clock_mc.rotation;
```

i need this method on Cocoa Touch

Comment: This question is not clear.  Can you reword it?  You want to _get_ some information?  What do you want to get?  Your question title mentions getting "objects degrees" -- what does that mean?  But in the question you are asking about "RADIAN".  Thanks in advance for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly then a bit of mathematics can help here:

```
angleInRadians = angleInDegrees * M_PI / 180.0
```

To get the reverse, you reverse your equation. So first moving the division by 180 on the right to the left results in multiplying by 180.0

```
angleInRadians * 180.0 = angleInDegrees * M_PI
```

Now move the multiply by M_PI (the value of PI which is something like 3.1415962...) to the left, you reverse the operation:

```
(angleInRadians * 180.0) / M_PI = angleInDegrees
```

Now to make it nice for the program to use, we write it like so:

```
angleInDegrees = (angleInRadians * 180.0) / M_PI
```

So in your program, you could write your code like this:

```
var angleInDegrees = 0;

...    

angleInDegrees = mcount * 180.0 / M_PI;
```

If you want to use a function then:

```
-(float) getAngleInDegrees:(float) radians
{
    float angleInDegrees = 0;

    angleInDegrees = radians * 180.0 / M_PI;

    return angleInDegrees;
}
```

Comment: If you want better performance you can use a macro instead of a method. `#define rad2deg(rad) (rad * 180.0f / M_PI)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want how to convert degrees into radians:-

for this you can use this formula:-

```
static inline double radians (double degrees) { return degrees * M_PI/180; }
```

Comment: this methods gives you radians value not degrees value

Comment: i know , but i want Degree Of My Object that input in your function!

Comment: i have Action Script 3 example :  myInt = clock_mc.rotation;  i need this method on Cocoa Touch

Answer (score 0):

*UPDATED!*

Do you want to get result rotation angle of `Clock` object?! If so, use this:

```
double rotationInRadians = atan2(Clock.transform.b, Clock.transform.a);
int rotationInDegrees = (int)round(rotationInRadians * 180 / M_PI);
```

Read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH204-CJBECIAD) for details & explanation.

Comment: i have Action Script 3 example :  myInt = clock_mc.rotation;  i need this method on Cocoa Touch